# What positioning method was used to get user location?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

Is there any way to know what positioning method was used when I receive location from CLLocationManager (standard location service) -  gps, cell, wifi?

Comment: Whenever I've used this I've just received a string for each coordinate or a formatted string for both and there didn't appear to be anyway to ascertain the method used.

Comment: you can know how precise the machine thinks the number is... which is probably what you really want.